# Get the required key of a php object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object

I have a select info that looks like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
$arrays = DB::table('users')->where('id', Session::get('user_id'))->get();
```

And when I echo out `$arrays`, I get something like:

```
[{"id":2,"first_name":"Mukesh","last_name":"Aryal","birth_date":"2002-08-23","email":"aryalmukesh60m@gmail.com","password":"4cb22531c6a79ae334e9e9ca95575394","profession":"Student","gender":"male","age":15,"bio":"maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","preferred_people":"Anyone eXPLORE! Would Prefer","profile_picture":"me.jpg","full_name":"Mukesh Aryal","joined_date":"2018-04-29","user_json":"'{\"first_name\":\"Mukesh\",\"last_name\":\"Aryal\",\"birth_date\":\"2002-8-23\",\"birth_date_in_string\":\"23 August 2002\",\"email_address\":\"aryalmukesh60m@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"4cb22531c6a79ae334e9e9ca95575394\",\"profession\":\"Student\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"age\":\"15\",\"bio\":\"maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"profile_picture\":\"me.jpg\",\"full_name\":\"Mukesh Aryal\",\"joined_date\":\"2018-04-29\",\"joined_date_in_string\":\"29 April 2018\",\"friends\":[],\"posts\":[],\"address\":\"\",\"searches\":[],\"nickname\":\"\",\"likedSubjects\":[],\"facebookProfile\":{},\"twitterProfile\":{}}'"}]
```

Now, How do `echo` out just the `first_name` from the whole object?

Comment: `$arrays->first_name` will solve your problem. And use `first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: I got an error that says:
**Property [first_name] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('id', Session::get('user_id'))->first();
```

This will yield a single row / object, which is easy to access:

```
$user->first_name
```

Comment: That was it!!! Thank You!!!! I will select this is the accepted answer the time when the site shows. (currently 10 mins after!) Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data='[{"id":2,"first_name":"Mukesh","last_name":"Aryal","birth_date":"2002-08-23","email":"aryalmukesh60m@gmail.com","password":"4cb22531c6a79ae334e9e9ca95575394","profession":"Student","gender":"male","age":15,"bio":"maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","preferred_people":"Anyone eXPLORE! Would Prefer","profile_picture":"me.jpg","full_name":"Mukesh Aryal","joined_date":"2018-04-29","user_json":"\'{\"first_name\":\"Mukesh\",\"last_name\":\"Aryal\",\"birth_date\":\"2002-8-23\",\"birth_date_in_string\":\"23 August 2002\",\"email_address\":\"aryalmukesh60m@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"4cb22531c6a79ae334e9e9ca95575394\",\"profession\":\"Student\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"age\":\"15\",\"bio\":\"maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"profile_picture\":\"me.jpg\",\"full_name\":\"Mukesh Aryal\",\"joined_date\":\"2018-04-29\",\"joined_date_in_string\":\"29 April 2018\",\"friends\":[],\"posts\":[],\"address\":\"\",\"searches\":[],\"nickname\":\"\",\"likedSubjects\":[],\"facebookProfile\":{},\"twitterProfile\":{}}\'"}]';

$data=json_decode($data,true);
echo $data[0]['first_name'];
```

This will print you the first_name. If you have more nested arrays you are going to need a loop of course. Something like this:

```
$data=json_decode($data,true);

foreach($data as $row){
    echo $row['first_name'];
}
```

Comment: The fact that the author get's a JSON array is because of the fact that Laravel turns an array response into JSON ;)